# Corners cut CSS

Tags: css

[image: Cutoff corners on buttons]
[image: Cutoff corners on buttons]

I'm trying to create buttonswith the cutoff corners being transparent? I have a first approach which basically consists of 1 :before and 1 :after element, therefore removing the unnecesarry borders of the original box with a fixed color and I just add the inner border, but this creates the issue that those after and before elements can not be transparent, they look like this:

[image]

**Just to be clear, I know how to move the elements, I'm just looking for a different approach that allows those cutoff parts to be transparent.**

Comment: Can you include the HTML and CSS that you have currently?

Comment: Just use a clip path, much simpler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have [an online generator](https://css-generators.com/custom-corners/) and a [detailed article](https://css-tricks.com/cut-corners-using-css-mask-and-clip-path-properties/) for this:

[image: CSS cut corner generator]

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border:none;
  background: none;
}

button:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background: red;
  clip-path: polygon(0 30.00px,30.00px 0,100% 0,100% calc(100% - 30.00px),calc(100% - 30.00px) 100%,0 100%,0 30.00px,5px  calc(30.00px + 2.07px),5px calc(100% - 5px),calc(100% - 30.00px - 2.07px) calc(100% - 5px),calc(100% - 5px) calc(100% - 30.00px - 2.07px),calc(100% - 5px) 5px,calc(30.00px + 2.07px) 5px,5px calc(30.00px + 2.07px));;
}
```

```html
<button> some text here </button>
```

Here is another idea with a code where you can adjust CSS variable if you don't want to generate a code

```css
button {
  --border: 5px;    /* the border width */
  --slant: 0.7em;   /* control the slanted corners */
  --color: #37E8FC; /* the color */
  
  font-size: 35px;
  padding: 0.4em 1.2em;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: var(--color);
  background: 
     linear-gradient(to bottom right,var(--color)  50%,#0000 50.1%) top left,
     linear-gradient(to top    left ,var(--color)  50%,#0000 50.1%) bottom right;
  background-size: calc(var(--slant) + 1.3*var(--border)) calc(var(--slant) + 1.3*var(--border));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow:
    0 0 0 200px inset var(--s,#0000),
    0 0 0 var(--border) inset var(--color);
  clip-path: 
      polygon(100% 0, var(--slant) 0, 0 var(--slant),
              0 100%, calc(100% - var(--slant)) 100%,100% calc(100% - var(--slant))
             );
  transition: color var(--t,0.3s), background-size 0.3s;
}
button:focus-visible {
  outline-offset: calc(-1*var(--border));
  outline: var(--border) solid #000c;
  clip-path: none;
  background-size: 0 0;
}
button:hover,
button:active{
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  color: #fff;
  --t: 0.2s 0.1s;
}
button:active {
  --s: #0005;
  transition: none;
}



body {
  display:grid;
  grid-auto-flow:column;
  grid-gap:20px;
  place-content:center;
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
<button style="--color:#f3738a;--border:3px;--slant:.5em">Button</button>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much.